# how to compare the seconds between two dates to an integer in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, date

i want to compare the seconds between two dates to an integer, but the result is not expected.

```
WITH m AS (
 SELECT to_date('2023-03-01 12:00:00','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') in_time,
        to_date('2023-03-01 12:00:30','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') out_time
 FROM dual
)

SELECT
(out_time-in_time)*24*60*60 delta_seconds,
(CASE WHEN (out_time-in_time)*24*60*60=30 THEN 'equal' else 'not equal' end) flag
FROM m
```

the result is

```
delta_seconds | flag
  30          | not equal
```

i thought the result is

```
delta_seconds | flag
  30          | equal
```

why?

Answer (score 4):

The subtraction of two dates gives you the result as a fraction of some number of days, which you then multiply by 86400 to get seconds. The fraction is not exact:

```
WITH m AS (
 SELECT to_date('2023-03-01 12:00:00','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') in_time,
        to_date('2023-03-01 12:00:30','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') out_time
 FROM dual
)

SELECT
(out_time-in_time)*24*60*60 delta_seconds,
(CASE WHEN (out_time-in_time)*24*60*60=30 THEN 'equal' else 'not equal' end) flag
FROM m
```

| DELTA_SECONDS | FLAG |
| --- | --- |
| 29.99999999999999999999999999999999999998 | not equal |

Your client is rounding the number for display. You can see the same output in SQL*Plus or SQL Developer if you `set numwidth 41` or higher, which allows enough space for all those digits, the decimal point and a potential minus sign to be shown; with a smaller value like the default `10` it has to implicitly round to be able to show a result.

To get the result you want to need to manually round the number:

```
WITH m AS (
 SELECT to_date('2023-03-01 12:00:00','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') in_time,
        to_date('2023-03-01 12:00:30','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') out_time
 FROM dual
)

SELECT
round((out_time-in_time)*24*60*60) delta_seconds,
CASE WHEN round((out_time-in_time)*24*60*60)=30 THEN 'equal' else 'not equal' end flag
FROM m
```

| DELTA_SECONDS | FLAG |
| --- | --- |
| 30 | equal |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/EvsQrqdC)

---

You can also get the difference as an interval, if you have to cast the dates to timestamps first or convert the date subtraction to an interval; you can then compare that with an interval literal:

```
SELECT
extract(second from (cast(out_time as timestamp) - cast(in_time as timestamp))) delta_seconds,
CASE WHEN extract(second from (cast(out_time as timestamp) - cast(in_time as timestamp)))=30 THEN 'equal' else 'not equal' end flag
FROM m
```

| DELTA_SECONDS | FLAG |
| --- | --- |
| 30 | equal |

```
SELECT
cast(out_time as timestamp) - cast(in_time as timestamp) delta_interval,
CASE WHEN cast(out_time as timestamp) - cast(in_time as timestamp) = interval '30' second THEN 'equal' else 'not equal' end flag
FROM m
```

| DELTA_INTERVAL | FLAG |
| --- | --- |
| +000000000 00:00:30.000000 | equal |

```
SELECT
(out_time-in_time)*24*60*60 * interval '1' second delta_interval,
CASE WHEN (out_time-in_time)*24*60*60 * interval '1' second = interval '30' second THEN 'equal' else 'not equal' end flag
FROM m
```

| DELTA_INTERVAL | FLAG |
| --- | --- |
| +000000000 00:00:30.000000000 | equal |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/G9qxHc0X)